# Jquery div is selected by id, choose the value of class

Tags: php, jquery

how do i do that ? 
my html structure looks like this
EDIT: i have updated to html so it fits the rules.

```
<td id="1" class="LinkWrap"><a href="" class="link">link</a></td>
```

i use this code:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
$(this).parent();
//some ajax code
});
```

To select the td by the id LinkWrap, but i need the value of the class, 
the class' value is fetched by php && mysql and is the id of the element thats i fetched. therefor the value is not a constant i and i cant just say chose class with value 1 it could be 2 or 5932.

i need that value to my ajax script so i can insert when the user clicks that link.
if theres a better method please let me know :)

Comment: So you're using ID as classes and classes as IDs? I'd like to know the logic behind using a class to identify a _single_ element, while you don't mention how your IDs change.

Comment: hmm.. maybe i wrote something wrong... 
well i have edited my script from the orignial to that i store the data inside the id instead of the class ex: <td id="1" class="LinkWrap"> i do this because i want to insert it into the database when the user clicks the link and i want to know exactly where the user pressed the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the fact that it's not recommended to start class names with a number. Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the class attribute.

```
$(".link").click(function() {
   alert( $(this).parent().attr('class') ); 
});
```

Edit: You're better of using the data attribute as stated by others as well.

HTML

```
 <td data-rowid="1" class="LinkWrap"><a href="" class="link">link</a></td>
```

Javascript

```
$(".link").click(function() {
   alert( $(this).parent().data('rowid') ); 
});
```

Comment: thank you! 
btw could i write create another data-rowid? so i had data-rowid and data-rowuser ??

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're doing data storage in the `class` attribute. Classes cannot start with a digit, and this means your invalid usage may wind up causing glitches in some browsers. You'd be better off using jQuery's `data()` in conjunction with `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: ive decided to put the data into the id instead,
but how does that work? id love to know a better way than storing the data in the id :)

Comment: ID's can't start with a number either.

Answer (score 1):

Interstellar_Coder and wilbbe01 are both right in the execution but there is one thing in your code that is going to bite you.  The td has an ID that, if repeated, could cause you referencing issues.  id attributes should be unique across a DOM instance at peril of very unpredictable results across different browsers.

aside from that ceejayoz solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need is the following.

```
$(this).parent().attr('class');
```

Edit: Ditto the data attribute stated by others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as I mentioned in my comment, it seems you mixed up the classes and IDs, and to avoid the problem noted by ceeyajoz, I'd suggest using another approach:

```
$('.link').click(function(e){
   var the_id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');  //or parent().
   $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page_id='+the_id,
       success:function(response){
         alert(response);
       }
   });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And in your html:

```
<td class="LinkWrap" id="td_1"><a href="" class="link">link</a></td>
```

And in your php:

```
$id = $_GET['page_id'];
$id = str_replace('td_','',$id);
echo $id;
```

Comment: thank you :) pretty much the same jquery code i got figured out. thanks for the extra php, didnt think of that :( 
all the other codes worked as well thank you!